# I have a function and I would like to written test case

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

```
function sendError (req, res, error) {
    var status = 200
    status = getErrorCode(error)  // For Eg the getErrorCode returns 500 val

    // Send to client
    res.sendStatus(status)
}
```

We have written above function in my node.js and jquery application and we have written below test case for the above function but its failing in mocha. Please help me out.

TEST CASE(Written in mocha)

```
if('send status to client', function(done) {
    var req = {}
    var res = {}
    var error = {code:'ENODATA'}
    sendError(req,res,error)  
    //Calling send error function via rewire method
    assert.equal(res.status, 500)
    done()
})
```

Error:

> res.sendStatus is not a function

So my thinking is I am not passing proper response, so when it is trying to set `sendstatus` it is not able to. Somewhere I read the res should be the object of datatype of `res`(express module `res`) - I am not sure, if so how to give that `res` parameter?

Comment: You need to edit your question. This is too difficult to understand.

Comment: you passing an empty object as res to sendError and thererfore there are no methods attached to it.

Comment: How are you implementing sendError? Are you using express?

Comment: yes, I am using express